# Is there a function that gets the true, case sensitive path of a file on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows

I'm creating `std::filesystem` Lua bindings for a game, and I want to make sure that mods that use the bindings later on don't depend on Windows its case-insensitivity.

For example, `fopen("foo.txt", "w")` followed by `fopen("Foo.txt", "r")` on Windows reads the file, while on Linux it wouldn't, since Linux is case-sensitive. This concerns not just the filename, but the entire path, because assuming `bar/` exists, `fopen("bar/baz.txt", "w")` followed by `fopen("Bar/baz.txt", "r")` would work on Windows but fail on Linux as well. So while the mod may work on Windows, it'd break for Linux users, which I want to prevent.

Previously I tackled this problem by "making" Linux case-insensitive using the [code here](https://github.com/cortex-command-community/Cortex-Command-Community-Project/blob/dd9522fac1997c2c39cd553c5456f0c2dcdd14e2/Source/Managers/LuaMan.cpp#L982-L1010), which essentially builds a path up, one parent directory at a time, by iterating over all the entries in the directory and checking whether the names match case-insensitively.

This solution's code isn't very elegant and quite large however, and now that I've decided that I want to do the exact opposite by "making" Windows be case-sensitive, I am hoping there's maybe some function I can use on Windows to get the true case-sensitive path of a file, so that `fopen("Foo.txt", "r")` would fail on *both* OSes.

I have Googled a lot and looked on SO for any others who have asked this before, but most answers were either snarky "Why would anyone need that", or do the equivalent of my current solution I linked above.

I've tried using `GetFullPathName()` for example by putting this in a `foo.cpp` file, but it prints `C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\Foo.cpp`, so isn't useful since I need `Foo.cpp` to be the same case as the actual file name:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    char filename[] = "Foo.cpp";
    char fullFilename[MAX_PATH];

    GetFullPathName(filename, MAX_PATH, fullFilename, nullptr);
    std::cout << fullFilename << std::endl;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `FindFirstFile` is the first tool I usually reach for for these sorts of things

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thank you very much! :) If you could post this as an answer I can accept it

Comment: @RetiredNinja So while your suggestion of using `GetLongPathName` seemed to work at first, it doesn't always give the parent directories the proper casing. If I take the program from my question and put it in `C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\abcdefgh\Foo.cpp`, and change the filename variable's value to `"C:/Users/<user>/Desktop/ABCDEFGH/Foo.cpp"` it works, but if I add an `i` at the end it doesn't, with the directory `C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\abcdefghi\Foo.cpp` and filename value `"C:/Users/<user>/Desktop/ABCDEFGHI/Foo.cpp"`. It does lowercase Foo.cpp, but not its parent directory. :/

Comment: Don't. Just don't. Leave it alone. Don't touch it. Don't write any such code. This is not what your users expect. I would be *extremely* frustrated and disappointed if any of programs that I use behaved this way, and I would certainly demand my money back and/or send bug reports.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The strategy is to open the file and retrieve the file path that is actually opened (With [`GetFinalPathNameByHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfinalpathnamebyhandlew)):

```cpp
struct HandleCloser {
    HANDLE h;
    ~HandleCloser() { ::CloseHandle(h); }
};

std::wstring final_path(const wchar_t* file_name) {
    HANDLE fp = ::CreateFileW(
        /*lpFileName=*/file_name,
        /*dwDesiredAccess=*/0,
        /*dwShareMode=*/FILE_SHARE_DELETE|FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        /*lpSecurityAttributes=*/nullptr,
        /*dwCreationDisposition=*/OPEN_EXISTING,
        /*dwFlagsAndAttributes=*/FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS|FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT,
        /*hTemplateFile=*/nullptr);
    // (FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS to work on directories and
    // FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT to work on symlinks)
    if (fp == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        // Handle error...
        return {};
    }
    HandleCloser _{fp};
    std::wstring result;
    result.resize(MAX_PATH);
    DWORD size = ::GetFinalPathNameByHandleW(
        fp, result.data(), result.size() + 1u, FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED
    );
    if (size > result.size()) {
        result.resize(size);
        size = ::GetFinalPathNameByHandleW(
            fp, result.data(), result.size() + 1u, FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED
        );
    }
    if (size == 0) {
        // Handle error...
        return {};
    }
    result.resize(size);
    return result;
}
```

It is crucial not to open the file with `FILE_FLAG_POSIX_SEMANTICS` because then the case-insensitive path translation won't happen. You don't need read/write permissions on the file for this. This will fail if the path doesn't exist, in which case you might want to traverse the subdirectories to see if they are in the correct case.

I think this is what [`std::filesystem::canonical`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/canonical) does with the Microsoft STL as well.

---

Alternatively, you can implement the Lua `fopen` on Windows to open with `FILE_FLAG_POSIX_SEMANTICS`. This will not allow you to read `Foo.txt` when `foo.txt` was written to and allows you to have two different files `Foo.txt` and `foo.txt`, even on Windows.